# Magento 2.3 Checkout success page 302 not found

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, cart

I am running Magento 2.3 and at the last stages of testing before going live. I have a problem with checking out, i add items into the cart, press check out, fill in the `information`, select `payment method` and hit **place order**  
this should go to the success page but it redirects back to the cart with no order in admin.

I've tried the usual commands as per forums but nothing's worked.

Comment: Go to stores configurations and disable redirect to base store 302 found. And then cache clean and cache flush. And run your test in incognito window

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a PDF Invoice extension, not quite sure how they're related but sorted it by removing it. I disabled all 3rd party extensions and enabled them one by one until the problem appeared again.